# Target a certain entry type on the entries fieldtype

Tags: entries, fieldtypes

I have all of my entries as single pages, but of different types depending on the section. I need to create a field that allows users to link to another page entry, but I need to ensure they only select one of a certain type.

Is it possible to only allow users to choose entries of a certain type using the entries field? I can't see the option, so perhaps if not there's a plugin that could do this? Has someone come across a good solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible by default in Craft. Check out the [Entries Subset plugin](https://github.com/nfourtythree/craft-entriessubset), though, I think it can do what you want.

Comment: Perfect. Exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 1):

I came here for the same reason as @Plasticated. Please mention, that there's also a release of the Entries Subset plugin (as suggested by @André) for Craft 3.

see Github: [Entries Subset plugin for Craft CMS 3.x](https://github.com/nfourtythree/craft3-entriessubset)

*EDIT:*
I recently tried to `composer require` the plugin as stated in the README file which resulted in an error. Instead don't use Composer to install that plugin as documented currently. You have to buy it using Craft's new plugin store. I already created an [issue for fixing the README](https://github.com/nfourtythree/craft3-entriessubset/issues/4).

*EDIT 2:*
Alright, the author has added his plugin to Packagist, therefore the installation will work without hazzle.

**Long story, short**
Try using [the plugin](https://github.com/nfourtythree/craft3-entriessubset). You can install it using Composer:
`composer require nfourtythree/entriessubset`